# ListBox not getting all selected items

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a ListBox which  is populated dynamically from a database in the code behind. I have another button and when i click the button, the button click event will get the all the selected listitem and insert the list item text to the database. I set AutoPostBack as false and EnableViewState is true in the listbox property

The problem is when i click the button , it only see 1 selected item even i select multiple items.Here are the codes. I appreciate your help. I spend 1 day on this issue and not getting anywhere.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {    
            loadrdlist();
        }  
} 

protected void loadrdlist()
{
         ((ListBox)TestFormView.FindControl("ListBoxB")).Items.Clear();

        foreach (FailureTempRD rd in FailureTempRD.SelectFailureTempRD())
            ((ListBox)TestFormView.FindControl("ListBoxB")).Items.Add(new ListItem(rd.ReferenceDesignator, rd.ReferenceDesignator)); 
}

protected void btn_AddRD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem rd in ((ListBox)TestFormView.FindControl("ListBoxB")).Items) //This is where it only see 1 selected item
     {
        if (rd.Selected == true) 
           //put selected item to database
        }
    }
}
```

Here are both listbox and button

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBoxB" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" ></asp:ListBox>
<asp:Button ID="btn_AddRD" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"  onclick= "btn_AddRD_Click" Text="Add" />
```

Update :
I figure why. When i load the listitem, i need to add ID as listitem value. So change the following code. I test few times and it works as intend.

```
 ((ListBox)TestFormView.FindControl("ListBoxB")).Items.Add(new ListItem(rd.ReferenceDesignator, rd.ReferenceDesignator));
```

To

```
 ((ListBox)TestFormView.FindControl("ListBoxB")).Items.Add(new ListItem(rd.ReferenceDesignator, rd.ID));
```

Comment: Is ListBox inside a Gridview??

Comment: Sorry , the list box and button are both in formview. I edit my post and the formview is in Insert Mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [GetSelectedIndices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.getselectedindices.aspx) Method.

From above link:

> Use the GetSelectedIndices method to identify or access the selected
>   items in the ListBox control. Each element in the returned array
>   represents the index for a selected list item. You can use the index
>   values to access the items in the Items collection.

Comment: I tried it and it still only see one selection. int[] selectedItems =((ListBox)Gridview.FindControl("ListBoxB")).GetSelectedIndices(); selectedItem.Length is 1

Comment: what is your [ListSelectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listselectionmode.aspx) set to.

Comment: You should be returning the indices of all of your selected Items. Is the item that is returning as selected, the First or Last or ? and if you iterated through your listbox, are all of your items showing up?

Comment: Thanks Mark, i think i figure out why. I update the change at top.

Comment: @windforceus You need to put your solution as an answer to your question and mark it as the answer when the system lets you.